# AndroidStudio 毎回フルコンパイルしないといけない

Tags: android-studio

AndroidStudioで再生マークのようなものをおした時、ソースコードが最新のものではなく
前回ビルドしたもので実行されるようになりました。
そのため、現在はソースコードを多少でも変更する度にフルコンパイルしないといけない状態です。

設定はいじっていませんがAndroidStudioはバージョンアップしました。
バージョンは２．０プレビュー９
です（多分最新）

Mac版でAndroid端末はシュミレータで実行しています。

再生マークのようなもので実行した時に変更されたソースだけ（最低限）コンパイルして実行させるように戻す方法をご存知の方いましたらお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

最新というか、正式版の最新は 1.5.1 なので、2.0 Preview 9 だとバージョン的に先走りですね。

[Instant Run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) は 2.0 での目玉となっている機能です。Preview 版を使用するのであれば、その辺りの新しく導入された機能回りの情報はチェックしておいた方が無難です。

`Settings/Preferences`から`Build, Execution, Deployment`の`Instant Run`の設定を見て、**`Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resources changes on deploy`** にチェックが入って有効になっているか、確認してみてください。

Comment: 確かにVSとかみたいに動的に反映されるようになったんだーとは思いましたが、そこまで頭が回りませんでした
ありがとうございます